# Access Query - Sum of Field based on newest for each day

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have the following data:

```
 Site # | Site Name | Product | Reading Date   | Volume
      1 | Cambridge | Regular | 02/21/17 08:00 | 40000
      2 | Cambridge | Regular | 02/22/17 07:00 | 35000
      3 | Cambridge | Regular | 02/22/17 10:00 | 30000
```

What I want to achieve is get the SUM of [Volume] of the last 30 days while taking the newest reading EACH day possible since its pretty inconsistent whether one day there are 1,2 or 3 readings. I have tried a couple of things but can't get it to work.

This is what I've tried:

```
SELECT [Site #], Product, Sum(Volume) AS SumOfVolume, DatePart("d",InventoryDate]) AS Day

FROM [Circle K New]

GROUP BY [Site #], Product, Day

HAVING (([Site #]=852446) AND (Product ="Diesel Lows"))

ORDER BY DatePart("d",[Inventory Date]) DESC;
```

Result:

[image]

It adds the two readings of the same day. I was/am thinking about just getting a daily average then finding the monthly average from that. But I'm unsure if the value changes affect average numbers.

Comment: Please post the code or sql you have tried.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Folks here are excited and eager to help you with your question but it's important to help them help you. Consider building a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's important because it shows what you've already tried, your thought process, and what you're hoping to achieve. Also consider using [backticks](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) for code sections, it increases readability. For example `41 + 1 = 42` is easier to read than 41 + 1 = 42. Again welcome and good skills moving forward :)

Comment: I have edited it. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description:

```
select sum(volume)
from data as d
where d.readingdate in (select min(d2.readingdate)
                        from data as d2
                        group by int(d2.readingdate)
                       ) and
      d.readingdate >= dateadd("d", -30, date());
```

Comment: Might be select max(d2.readingdate) instead of min(d2.readingdate)? The rest looks good, tho.

Comment: Tried this and Im getting no results, query comes blank.